# How do you get line breaks to show up in web email message using MVC smtp message body?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, line-breaks

I'm either crazy or there is no previous answer that I can understand(it could happen).

Gmail shows this in an email body (using IIS on devbox, hence "localhost" in link):

Please confirm your account by clicking this link: http://localhost:53891/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=526b54e1-2275-4bb0-bc8347289f413a69&code=ErXrRF8f%2BPZFK43WxwxQJjfT7%2BIIgd6HhglTNq8btRDdRZwbBxgwtmtuGhBDozgr9vyy2cy%2Bs0yweATeY4Hgv6BmjtOK7fJ7S2rS%2B8ShjhILM7kXZNqMBK4sTGSHoSozURZRgfTQcSB2OBgTFk8v%2BvlslF5Xsilz
%2Bd0OwnJz6KwOqNzzMrB6DgUyjUAIOJTt Or click on and copy the link in your browser.

it works when I click on it and it registers me, but I can't seem to format it so it has breaks/linefeeds. Devil is in the details lol!

Here is my MVC IdentityConfig.cs that sends the email:

```
               string html = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Please confirm your account by clicking this link: " + 

Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + message.Body);
               html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Environment.NewLine);
               html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Environment.NewLine);
               html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Environment.NewLine);
               html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Or click on and copy the link in your browser.");
               html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't supplying html with the replace.

```
html = html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Right?

Edit: Further example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/slm90h

```
    string html = "";
    html += Environment.NewLine;
    html += Environment.NewLine;
    html += Environment.NewLine;
    html += Environment.NewLine;
    html += Environment.NewLine;
    html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
    Console.WriteLine(html);
    Console.WriteLine("^---- Doesn't work");
    html = html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
    Console.WriteLine(html);
    Console.WriteLine("^----- Does work");
```

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what you are saying. html is a string variable and should fill up with the replacement. Unless Environment.NewLine isn't html. . .do you have a suggestion? When the message is created (second code block) nobody sees it. So I might not be using the correct newline syntax for C# code. Thanks for answering so quick.

Comment: Replace method returns string.  If you aren't doing anything with the return data, then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with .NET Fiddle. I am using the html string in the message body of the email, and I post that in the first code block of my question. No line breaks, or wrong syntax for line breaks. no nothing but straight text.

Comment: Your data at the top is still wrong.  html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"); will not update your html variable.  It will only return a string that replaces .NewLine with <br />.   My .net fiddle shows your code first (html.Replace(xxx) by itself) and then shows my way where you do html = html.Replace(xxx).  You have to apply the result of the method to a variable or it just gets lost to nowhere.

Comment: I already knew that nothing was showing up. I needed a solution thinking I had to encode it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set IsBodyHtml = true; ?

Comment: yes. I understand your question. There are 2 configurations: text and html.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. It was simpler than I thought. And there was no need to htmlEncode because the html is in an email page, not a webpage. (I think that makes sense).
I took off all the Environment.Newline and htmlEncode and just put in an html break.

```
   string html = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: " + "<br /><br />" + message.Body;
   html += "<br /><br /><br />";
   html += "Or click on and copy the link in your browser.";
```

And here is what came through in the email message body (all the breaks happened):

Please confirm your account by clicking this link:

http://localhost:xxxxx/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=c56dfcd7-e63e-4a08-8c38-16419d8ff1c9&code=WgoxvI%2FEdCUjMgJwnXgZ3siP1vKSE1%2BlJ5SCX%2FjL3GPwk7kmycRrdVeNDygl65gQ3HuOlmid1iYKNaX6pRhBTNuBDk0dMM7w%2F%2BOnC%2BkE1vXHRDV1cv9Fcifk4i51ZXQef9%2BoKVfCPeqjYZoDPnQBsxZzYJEiVSSn8NvEBdjYG%2FpE1CM7QeShH9oDB2XJ1nFC

Or click on and copy the link in your browser.